# Start and Stop OpenOffice Service using Java code?

Tags: java, openoffice.org, libreoffice, openoffice-calc, file-conversion

I have OpenOffice installed on both a Windows and a Linux machine. I want to write a simple Java application that will connect to OpenOffice remotely and do some file conversion. I want to run OpenOffice as a service on both Windows and Linux on some random port. After the file conversion is done, I want to stop the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start first :

```
soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard
```

then use some library to connect and use the service like [jodconverter](https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/)

To call an executable from java :

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\PathToExe\\MyExe.exe","param1","param2").start();
```

You gave him your path to openoffice exe, then each parameter (`-headless`...)

[more infos in runtime.exec](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec_envp.htm)

Comment: Thanks @flafoux. Appreciate your time. Yeah the approach works fine in Windows environment. I want to make it generic solution. It should work on Linux environment as well. Any thoughts about it.

Comment: Only the path to exe change, so you have to find a way to make it an argument that the user give, or through a configuration file

Comment: Ok stopping the Service can be done by obtaining the process id and killing it when the work is done. I am right with this approach?

Comment: as far as I know, yes killing process is the way to stop the office service